# How Do I setup SQL Database Mirroring In Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have setup 3 Azure SQL Server VM's, one primary, one secondary and one witness server. They are all within the same cloud service. I have mirrored a database and everything looks like its working.

1. How do I get the other VM's within the virtual network to use the SQL mirroring I have setup without pointing them directly to the primary SQL servers IP address? Point them to the external SQL cloud service public IP? or DNS name?
2. and If so, How does the Azure SQL VM's mirroring work? When I point the internal VM's to the cloud service, does it just magically know what server to point it to that is the primary? and what if the primary goes down for some reason, does the cloud service know to point traffic to the secondary now (hoping that it flipped to the secondary SQL server) I assume that the witness server has something to do with this, but I am unsure how the cloud service is going to know anything happened.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, the supported setup on Azure is using AlwaysOn Availability Groups.  Detailed steps to setup and use are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870963.aspx  You also need to make sure your listener is configured correctly as per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376546.aspx.  Clients will use the Listener as their connection and the Listener will route the request to the right active node.

Comment: But the client is using the SQL standard not enterprise. Only enterprise had the always on, this is why we were using the mirroring, because the Microsoft site said that this is the only way to have HA. thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't matter what license the customer has unless they have license mobility enabled in their agreement with Microsoft.  The cost of SQL instances running on Virual Machines in Azure by default includes the cost of SQL Server.

Comment: I think that you or I is missing something. They are running standard SQL server within Azure, their only option according to MS is that they have to run Mirroring to achieve HA. I was asking how I get the internal VM's running within the same Azure Virtual Network to make sure that its pointed properly to the mirrored set of SQ servers.

Comment: No different to on-premise mirroring then.  Your applications / clients must be failover aware (i.e. in .net you must provide a failover partner in the connection string).  This is why you must have exactly the same SQL login details on both instances (or use the same AD domain login).  Your Azure VMs will have a private IP like every other machine on your VNET.  You can now reserve IPs for a VM so it doesn't change between reboots too.